# How can I temporary disable "low battery" UIAlertView on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, alert, uialertview, battery

I'm developing something like a stopwatch, so I have to **turn off that below 20% battery alert view** somehow during a time measuring session (I will inform the user about battery percentage elsehow).

I just couldn't google for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using the public iPhone SDK.

Comment: Whoa.

Then what is the best way to ask for the battery percentage?
UIDevice class? Is the system alert launched on an actual 20% (Maybe I can inform the user on 30% before starting a time measuring session)?

Comment: To get the battery life, you can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]`, which will give you a float between 0.0 and 1.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469549/iphone-calculating-battery-life explains how to get notifications about battery life.