# How to find maximum capacity and current available capacity of battery in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, battery, batterylevel, iphone-sdk-2

In my application I can find the battery level using `[[UIDevice currentdevice] batterylevel]`, it is working only in 3.0 or later versions. I don't know how to find the maximum capacity and currently available capacity of battery. Also, how can I find the battery level and battery status in iOS 2.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone: Calculating battery life](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469549/iphone-calculating-battery-life)

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly available way to find the battery capacity, and no way to find the charge level before iOS 3.0. If you want to use private APIs, you might be able to use code such as [this](http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/).

Comment: Also Apple does not allow any apps submit that support iOS 2.*, the minimum is now 3.*