# Estimated battery time on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone: Calculating battery life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469549/iphone-calculating-battery-life)

I have seen many apps in appstore which provides Estimated battery work time for different usage patterns (standby, audio and video playback, Wi-Fi and 3G browser usage, talk time). I have a similar requirement to compute the estimated time like this. Can someone throw some light on how to do this programmatically?

Comment: http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/ read this blog, may help  you

Answer (score 4):

The battery life specs come from [Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html).

- Talk time: Up to 8 hours on 3G, up to 14 hours on 2G (GSM)
- Standby time: Up to 200 hours
- Internet use: Up to 6 hours on 3G, up to 9 hours on Wi-Fi
- Video playback: Up to 10 hours
- Audio playback: Up to 40 hours

The code to get the percentage of battery left is:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [myDevice batteryLevel];
```

That's all Apple and the iOS give you, so anything else an app uses is guesswork.